# Installing Graphite on OS-X Lion. How to configure apache2?

Tags: python, macos, apache2, graphite

I'm trying to configure graphite locally. The instructions are pretty straight forward and easy to follow [(see here)](http://graphite.wikidot.com/installation), right up to the part about configuring apache2, where the instructions become vague, and none of the options seem to apply to OS-X. Downloading the graphite source didnt provide an example "vhost.conf" as described in the installation guide, and my apache2 directory (/etc/apache2) doesnt have any of the following directories that the instructions might be options: sites-available, sites-enables, /conf/vhosts.d/

do i need to make these directories? if so what do i put there once they're created. how do i modify httpd.conf, aside from allowing mod_python? sorry for what is probably the most basic of apache questions, but i've never done this before!

Answer (score 4):

There's a script to start a simple development server included with graphite. I have graphite installed to `/opt/graphite`, so it's `/opt/graphite/bin/run-graphite-devel-server.py`

usage:

```
run-graphite-devel-server.py /path/to/graphite/install
```

eg:

```
/opt/graphite/bin/run-graphite-devel-server.py /opt/graphite
```

edit: There are a *lot* of extras that aren't included in the release package but are included if you check out graphite from their source repository. Even though it's a little more difficult (although not too difficult if you use the github mirror of their bazaar repo), I recommend building graphite from source. (thanks @jabley for mentioning it wasn't in the release tarball).

Comment: Sadly this script doesn't seem available in the current release, but you can get it from https://raw.github.com/tmm1/graphite/d0f76a659f4f2dea67f19902002710f601f534aa/bin/run-graphite-devel-server.py Upvoted your answer since I found it useful, even though it doesn't directly answer the OP!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
<IfModule !wsgi_module.c>
        LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
</IfModule>
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/apache2/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName graphite.local
        DocumentRoot "/opt/graphite/webapp"
        ErrorLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/error.log
        CustomLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/access.log common
        WSGIDaemonProcess graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120 python-path=/opt/graphite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
        WSGIProcessGroup graphite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIImportScript /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi 
        Alias /content/ /opt/graphite/webapp/content/
        <Location "/content/">
                SetHandler None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from localhost
        </Location>
        Alias /media/ "@DJANGO_ROOT@/contrib/admin/media/"
        <Location "/media/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>
        <Directory /opt/graphite/conf/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```